# What linear voltage regulator alternatives are there for use in IOT applications?

Tags: arduino, voltage-regulator, analog, linear-regulator

I had been having problems auto-uploading reliably to a ESP board that I have designed. It would sometime upload the program and sometimes it wouldn't. Seemingly completely at random.

The issue was solved when someone advised that the issue might be a power problem.  That led me to question the HT7333 I used in the circuit, because apparently it had horrible transient response which was the reason why the auto-upload wouldn't work well.

[image]

That small fall on Vout is actually a drop from 3.64V down to 2.76V. Which isnt that so small what so ever.

The solution was to install 100uF capacitors at its input and output. The same problem exists also with some DOIT Devkit ESP32s, which shows me that the AMS1117 that they use should also have the same issue. The gentleman that pointed this out recommended that I may use AP2112 instead.

What other alternatives are there to the well known HT and AMS1117 for 3.3V and 5V voltage levels respectively? I would very much appriciate it if you would share your experiences.

Comment: If that's really a 900 mV transient, then you also have 500 mV or so of noise on the power supply. Check your probing method, scope bandwidth, scales, etc, and make sure you're measuring what you think you're measuring.

Comment: If that's a 900mV transient then your 3.64V power supply is actually about 6-7V. Which it isn't, or the magic smoke would come out.

Comment: *What Linear Voltage Regulators are there that are adequate for use in IOT apllications?* I dare to say that **all LDOs are adequate**. Yes that is a **BOLD** statement! But if an LDO isn't adequate, the designer: 1) chose the wrong LDO for the job (for example the LDO has too low current capability) and/or 2) isn't using the LDO properly. My point: LDOs do not vary that much in performance so it should not have such an impact on your system. There are exceptions: for example noise and supply ripple rejection but for a "generic IOT application", that should not matter.

Comment: The measurment is from the datasheet. I didnt take it. It should be also similar for the 3.3V variant.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie But it does matter. The LDO choice and the lack of large capacitors is the reason why some ESP32 boards fail to initiate the auto-upload of sketches. IOT applications always involve a chip that is very sensetive to parasitic effects. Which is why I am looking for some alternative to the more popular chinese LDOs.

Comment: I've been using TI 'cap-free' type LDOs for a long time. They're designed to have good transient response, using an NMOS follower output.

Comment: No it doesn't, the transient response is mainly determined by the output capacitor. You cannot say that when the datasheet of LDO1 says: use 1 uF capacitors and the datasheet of LDO2 says: use 100 uF capacitors, that LDO2 is "better". It is **your choice as a designer** to select the capacitors that are needed. I dare to state that LDO1 with 100 uF capacitors will have **similar transient performance** as LDO2 with 100 uF capacitors. The capacitors suggested in the datasheet are usually **minimum values** that will guarantee stability. If you draw a pulsed current you should use larger caps.

Comment: In addition to "shopping" questions being off topic, questions seeking an open-ended list are also a prohibited form - an issues that seems to be shared by your previous auto-reset question.  Questions here need to be specific, eg, "if I do this I experience this problem"

Comment: *IOT applications always involve a chip that is very sensetive to parasitic effects* Why? What chip is that? What **proof** do you have? As an experienced engineer I see you chasing lots of "red herrings" (problems that you think are caused by A but they're actually caused by B). It is common in inexperienced designers but easy to combat: always ask **why?** and **how?**. You need proof to be able to draw conclusions.

Comment: @ChrisStratton okay, but if I want to expand my "library" of LDOs how should I structure my question? Because if I dont hear of different products how am I to better my designs? Right now I only use HT7333 or AMS1117. Which has shown me that they arent the top choice on occasion.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I know that it is the problem because after I added the 100uF caps it solved the issue for me. However 100uF capacitors take physically too much space. For me better would be something lik 47uF Tantalum caps. for instance.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie The wifi chips I have worked with are always sensetive to the parasitic effects on their VCC. Like the ESP32 or ESP8266

Comment: Stack Exchange isn't intended to fulfill every need you may have, rather it is intended to do only the things which it can do well.  "Expanding your library of LDO's" is not a goal it is designed to fulfill - you have the rest of the Internet to explore that.  But what SE is able to do is to try to call your attention to the likelihood that you misunderstand the actual problem.  Other people aren't experiencing issues with the regulators typically found on ESP8266 and ESP32 boards, so it's likely your issue comes from the *upstream* supply, additional loading you are adding, or something else.

Comment: @ChrisStratton yes other people have had the same problem with me even with ESP devkit that are so popular. Just take a look at this one if you dont beleive me.https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/issues/1274 I had the same problem as these people. Adding the 100uF capacitors solved it for me. It would also solve it for them. But i will close the thread if you so want me to. I thought it may help other young designers like me who have may have the same problem.

Comment: @EmreMUTLU Reading that issue, the problem stemmed from using crappy unknown components. Top tip for young designers: don't expect cheap copied components without a datasheet to work well. When I started out, I was shocked at the price of "professional" equipment, but you'll quickly realise it is worth every penny/cent/etc and you can focus on real engineering. So, for eg, buy one good bench power supply, rather than five no brand USB adapters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"What LDO for IoT" is too vague because "Internet of Things" is just huge. However, considering your choice of ESP32, we can narrow that down. So what parameters of this LDO are important and what parameters are not?

First requirement of any regulator is not to overheat:

- At max load and dropout voltage, it should handle the dissipation. P=IV, DeltaT = P*Rth, compute max dissipation power, find thermal solution ie ground plane heat sink*, compute max allowable RthJC, decide appropriate package, for instance SOT89 or SOT223 or something similar that has proper thermal path, ie not SOT23.
- Sub-requirement: when the thermal tab of your IC is GND things are simple because you have a ground plane already. If the tab is Vout, and you don't have a power plane, you have a problem. Sure AMS1117 is tiny but the tab is Vout, so it's like this chip feels so special it just requires you to dedicate a huge copper pour on your board for no other reason than to cool it, and that tiny SMD now takes as much space as a TO220. And now you'll try to shrink the copper pour because it takes too much space, and you'll have to spend time doing thermal calculations to know if it will fry, all this to save 2 cents. When the tab is GND, the whole ground plane is the heat sink.

Load is a micro, not sensitive analog electronics, therefore:

- Output noise: not important
- PSRR: meh, not important, it'll be powered from a regulated 5V or batteries anyway

But, it's a big dual core 240Mhz micro with a WiFi radio that draws substantial current spikes. It also has various sleep modes which means it can go from drawing microamps to 200mA in a really short time. So I'll interpret "LDO for IoT" as a LDO that can handle a load that sleeps then bursts.

- Transient response: important, especially steps between very low currents and nominal

Also an important parameter for implementation is output capacitor type. Some LDOs require capacitors with some amount of ESR for stability, and some are fine with a ceramic cap which has a tiny ESR of a few mOhms. Since ESP32 is sleek and thin, it would be good taste to associate it with ceramic caps.

So, for example, a LDO that costs 5 cents but feels special enough to require a 50c capacitor with "special ESR" ends up costing more than a 30 cents LDO that is happy with a 1 cent capacitor. And if the device is used outside in winter, the ESR of your non-ceramic caps will vary a lot... Will it always be stable?

ESP32 module has ceramic caps on its tiny PCB so the HF decoupling part is already done. So there is absolutely no technical reason that says it's not okay to stick a 1000µF electrolytic capacitor; but cost and aesthetics matter and MLCCs are cheap and tiny. Since ESP32 is a bit of a power hog, let's say 10µF. So:

- Output capacitor requirements: stable with 10µF X7R MLCC

If you were using a battery and not a 5V power supply, you might add conditions about:

- Quiescent current
- Dropout voltage (here we have 1.7V margin, so any LDO will do that)
- Transient response when dropout voltage is low

So, now you have all the required selection criteria to weed out the parts you don't want. Enter the info into the mouser/digikey search engine and... you'll probably have tons of results.

Sort by price, click on datasheets.

You're using ceramic caps on the output. So, Ctrl-F, "capa", ENTER. If it highlights "stable with ceramic caps", good. Otherwise, next. If it specs a minimum ESR value like 0.1 ohm or something, or i it says "requires tantalum" or "aluminium cap" on the output (which is another way to say "high ESR") then next.

For example this is the case with AMS1117. It says "22µF solid tantalum". Why put an expensive tantalum cap after a super cheap regulator? That's because it's an old chip design from the days when big ceramic caps were expensive. Now ceramics are cheap, so the new LDOs are pretty much all designed for ceramics. Cross-check with LM1117 datasheet:

[image]

So... next. Unless you put an aluminium cap, in this case it will work. With just ceramics it'll be unstable.

Note this is a different problem than HT7333. HT7333 is micropower, micropower regulators tend to be slow, and this one is extremely slow. It's probably designed for low power stuff that draws more or less constant current. AMS1117 is not slow, in fact it's pretty good, but its topology makes it unstable with low ESR caps, so it'll oscillate with ceramic caps. Result is the same, your micro will crash.

On AP2112 datasheet, hit Ctrl-F "capa" it says "Stable with 1.0µF Flexible Cap: Ceramic, Tantalum and Aluminum Electrolytic" like most modern LDOs.

So then you can check the rest of the specs.

How to read a transient response graph:

These vary a lot by manufacturer. Sometimes most of the information you need is obtained by noticing what is NOT shown on the graph.

The important thing is: during a load step will the voltage go out of the acceptable voltage range for the load?

Transconductance of PMOS used as pass device in LDOs increases with current, so at very low Iout you'll get higher output impedance and slower response. As current increases, transonductance increases, so things get snappier. If the graph shows "0 to max load step" then it's the worst case. If it shows "10mA to max load step" then they're not showing the worst case.

Likewise PMOS perform better with higher Vds. At low droupout voltage, when the PMOS begins to behave like a resistor, it needs a lot more gate drive so performance degrades. LDO behavior will be much worse at a dropout close to the lower limit than at say, 1 or 2 Volts. If the transient graphs say "Vin=Vout+2V" then it's not the worst case, and if you use it at a dropout of 0.5V it will be worse. If they show it for a dropout of say 0.5V then that's closer to a real use case.

Comment: From looking at some datasheets, a "stable with 1.0 μF ceramic" seems to also allow more than 1.0 μF.

Comment: Usually yes, more capacitance means more stable and better transient response, unless the datasheet specs a maximum capacitance value but that's rare... or if the output cap is so big that the LDO has problems charging it at start up.